# Can I use the iPad Pencil with Trello?

Tags: ipad, apple-pencil, trello

I would like to use a TODO app with the iPad pencil. I recently got an iPad with pencil and love it and would like to use it with Trello to have a weeks todo list without the hassle of setting dates in a calendar application.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Their [app page](https://apps.apple.com/app/trello-organize-anything/id461504587) doesnt say that pencil can be used with it. https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-onenote/id410395246 they show a demo

Answer (score 1):

My first generation Apple Pencil works with Trello on a 10.5" iPad Pro running iOS 13.2.

If it doesn't work for you, there are some Trello alternatives like Asana – there are really too many to list here! Since Trello works well for me, I haven't explored other options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just a little bit more information - on using it, for writing text, can you just draw on a card in Trello and it saves it in there? If you have a screenshot to show it in action, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood your original question – it was not entirely clear. Trello does not support using the iPad Pencil for handwriting as far as I know. It's also a free app (only has the cost of registration), so why not take it for a spin?